# How can I remove effect of gravity using LayoutParams method in Android? (Gravity.NO_GRAVITY doesn't work.)

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, layout-gravity

I have expected that TextView was aligned to the right because of `NO_GRAVITY`, however it was aligned to the left. Shouldn't `NO_GRAVITY` leave the gravity setting as it is, instead of aligning it to the left. If I also remove this two lines belove, it still aligns the TextView to the left even if I specify **android:layout_gravity="center"** in xml code.

```
params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
params.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;
```

How can I change other properties of the layout without effecting its gravity? What is exactly the difference between `LEFT` and `NO_GRAVITY`?

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
params.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Left forces left, while no gravity defaults the gravity to nothing. meaning left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Gravity.NO_GRAVITY` might (its just a guess) mean "default" gravity, which in your locale is left, but in some countries it might be right (arabic e.g., due to [writting direction](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)). if you want centered aligning then you can set `Gravity.CENTER`, obviusly...

if you want to combine two Gravities, then you can use flag add

```
params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
```

besides that if you are setting `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` then `textView`s parent must be `LinearLayout`. in rare cases with dynamic layouts and multiple threads  change in params shoud be continued with `requestLayout()` method call for forcing "redraw" in proper position and thread

Comment: I've changed layout **Orientation** to **horizontal** and changed `Gravity.RIGHT` to `Gravity.BOTTOM` in the code but still it is the same(aligned to top left). I know the difference between layout_gravity and gravity. Also i.e. I  am trying to set the whole TextView's alignment to right. My expectation had been that there wouldn't be any change on the gravity of the TextView after `NO_GRAVITY` was executed. My purpose is changing other properties of the layout without effecting its gravity as I said

Comment: show then XML and/or code for inflating. are you shure that `textView`s parent is `LinearLayout`? can you show its attributes?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:id="@+id/myLLayout">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:id="@+id/helloWorld"/>
    </LinearLayout>`

Comment: nothing suspicious here... you may try with `requestLayout()` call just after `setLayoutParams`. you didn't show Java code and place where you are changing these `LayoutParam`a, it may be the key